# Apply XSLT and XSD Schema to xml output via Jersey Rest

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, jaxb, jersey

Is there a way to apply an xsl and xsd to an xml output via REST services? I'm using Jersey 1.4 with JAXB 2.2 jre implementation. Thanks. Can't use MOXy or other JaxB implementations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a `javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput` from your JAX-RS service.  In your implementation of `StreamingOutput` you could use JAXB with XSLT and XSD.

```
public class MyStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

    private JAXBContext jc;
    private Transformer t;
    private XmlSchema s;
    private Object o;

    public MyStreamingOutput(JAXBContext jc, Transformer t, XmlSchema s, Object o) {
        this.jc = jc;
        this.t = t;
        this.s = s;
        this.o = o;
    }

    public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws java.io.IOException, WebApplicationException
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setSchema(s);
        JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(m,o):
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
        t.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but when I try to specify the source as a new Stream Source I get an systemID error even though I'm specifying an absolute path to the file. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Do you mean `StreamResult`?  Yes you will probably need to do  setSystemId(String).  Weird you are still seeing an exception.

Comment: `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamsSource(String SystemId))` when assigning `t`. Thats where I get the unknown `SystemId`. I'm putting the correct absolute path.